# Make the Touch Bar less fancy

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings, touch-bar, smart-keyboard

I got a mbp with Touch Bar and now I'm sure I don't like it. What can I do to make it look and behave less like a Touch Bar? Is it possible to make it hold just two sets of buttons, the function keys and the volume keys (and other keys we use to have when pressing fn)?

Here it looks like every time I switch apps the Touch Bar will show something different. I just want volume up/down and screen brightness up/down there all the time at one click distance. Is this still possible?

To access volume I have to 1st press the volume slider to get access to up/down buttons. I would like to volume up/down in just one click.

Comment: "Fancy" is subjective, but Better Touch Tool allows you to deeply customize the Touch Bar https://folivora.ai

Comment: Sure.  All the settings are in System Preferences.

Comment: @SteveChambers I don't want to customize it, I want it as it was in the old times. You touched exactly the point of the question.

Comment: @MarcWilson I see is possible to customize it. But how to make volume up/down and screen brightness up/down stuck there forever?

Comment: System Preferences > Keyboard

Answer (score 2):

In **System Preferences > Keyboard**, set "Touch Bar shows" to "Expanded Control Strip"

Answer (score 0):

To access the volume or brightness in just 1 tap, just press on the desired icon and start sliding your finger left or right without raising your finger.

I run my computer with the brightness slider, volume slider, mute, and quick actions. I see them in all of the apps that I'm in at all times. You'll find those default settings in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Customize Touch Bar..